# Merging 2 Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array with the following example structures:

```
$json1 = '[[
{
  "Str1":"ABC",
  "Str2": "Some Value",
  "Str3": "Something"
},
{
  "Str1": "DEF",
  "Str2": "Another Value",
  "Str3": "Test"
},
{
  "Str1": "GHI",
  "Str2": "NULL",
  "Str3": "Blah"
}]]';

$json2 = '[{
  "ID": "1",
  "ABC": "Hello",
  "DEF": "Test",
  "GHI": "Something"
}]';


$arr1 = json_decode($json1);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2);
```

I want them to join with PHP "by key". The keys are `ID`, `ABC`, `DEF`, (only example names) etc.

The keys are the names of the arrays in **Array 1**. Also, the first entry of every array in **Array 2** is. Unfortunately, they are in different orders.

So I need to iterate both arrays and check if the keys are the same, if so copy the values of **Array 2** to **Array 1**. Something like this:

```
if($array1[$key] == $array2[$key]){
    $array1[$key] += $array2[$key];
}
```

The desired result are just some array merged together by their "keys":

```
[0] => array(4){
"ABC" => "Hello",
"Str 1" => "ABC",
"Str 2" => "Some Value",
"Str 3" => "Something"
}
[1] => array(4){
"DEF" => "Test",
"Str 1" => "DEF",
"Str 2" => "Another Value",
"Str 3" => "Test"
}
[2] ...
```

Comment: I suppose that a foeach would be the appropriate way

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Please post a coherent example: two input arrays => desired array

Comment: @RaviHirani: I added the desired result.

Comment: @user1170330, does the initial `Array 1` always contain only one nested array with intended keys ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Yes, it does.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Tell us about the keys str1, str2 and str3?  If str1 is always the target key, and str2 is the value, what purpose does str3 serve?

Comment: @J.D.Pace: Str 1-3 are just regular content. This needs to be inside of the new (overall) array. The value of Str 1 is also the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
foreach ($arr1[0] as $key => $entry) {
    $arr1[0][$key][$arr1[0][$key]["Str1"]] = $arr2[0][$entry["Str1"]];
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "Str1":"ABC",
         "Str2":"Some Value",
         "Str3":"Something",
         "ABC":"Hello"
      },
      {  
         "Str1":"DEF",
         "Str2":"Another Value",
         "Str3":"Test",
         "DEF":"Test"
      },
      {  
         "Str1":"GHI",
         "Str2":"NULL",
         "Str3":"Blah",
         "GHI":"Something"
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$json1 = '[[
{
  "Str1":"ABC",
  "Str2": "Some Value",
  "Str3": "Something"
},
{
  "Str1": "DEF",
  "Str2": "Another Value",
  "Str3": "Test"
},
{
  "Str1": "GHI",
  "Str2": "NULL",
  "Str3": "Blah"
}]]';

$json2 = '[{
  "ID": "1",
  "ABC": "Hello",
  "DEF": "Test",
  "GHI": "Something"
}]';


$arr1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$arr_merged = array_fill_keys( array_keys($arr2[0], null );
foreach($json2[0] as $k => $v) {
        $arr_merged[$k] => array($v);
}
foreach($json1 as $src) {
    $key = $json1['Str1'];
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $arr_merged)) {
        $arr_merged[$key] = array();
    }
    foreach($src as $k => $v) {
        $arr_merged[$key][$k] = $v;
    }
}
```